# Application.commandbars force new menu to the end of the commandbar?

Tags: excel, vba

i have the below script which runs fine if i run it in it's current state but in a newer version of excel we have additional menus at the top of excel (Adobe and a few others) is there any way to force the menu to place at the last place possible on the right as currently (IMenuPos = 9 and iOffset = 0) it's not populating the menu automatically as there is a menu item already in item 9.

it also needs to ideally be the end of the menu not just +1 as other people in here have variable plugins in their excel which will then cause conflict so it will vary heavily

any advice on this would be great.

```
Set Menu = Application.CommandBars(iMenuBarIndex).Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, Before:=(iMenuPos + iOffset), Temporary:=True)
```

Comment: Why are you still using Commandbars rather than custom xml for the ribbon?